# Change the route in Aimeos Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am using Aimeos e-commerce on a Laravel site, I want to change the store route to /shop but I get an the browser doesn't open a page I do it as follows

```
Route::get('/shop', function () {
    return redirect('shop');
})->name('shop');
```

but when I make on "/" main page it displays perfectly. How to change its route?

Comment: What do you think `redirect('shop')` is doing?

Comment: this code is from aimeos core, I am guessing it just redirects to the shop main store page

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your route/web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('shop');
});
```

See https://github.com/aimeos/aimeos/blob/master/routes/web.php